# Kotlin apply on String not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, syntactic-sugar

I am trying to use all features of kotlin, but seems not of them are working, or may be it's my fault.

So, `apply` to `String` not work. Example:

```
val str = someStr.apply {
    toUpperCase()
    if (contains("W")) replace("W", "w")
}
```

> Input -> xywz
>
> Output -> xywz
>
> Expected -> XYwZ

Java style:

```
val str = it.text().toString().toUpperCase()
if (str.contains("W")) str.replace("W", "w")
```

> Input -> xywz
>
> Output -> XYwZ
>
> Expected -> XYwZ

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're looking for fancy ways to do simple things. Just take a look at TheOperator's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toUpperCase()` returns a copy of the string (strings are immutable). So you need to store the returned value, as a stand-alone (not last) statement inside `apply()` it is lost.

Also, you can't use `if` without `else`, if you return an expression. The `contains()` is not even needed in your case.

What you probably would like to do is call `toUpperCase()` and `replace()` directly:

```
val str = someStr.toUpperCase().replace("W", "w")
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) does not return the value you calculated. You may rather want to use either: [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) or [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html). Additionally, probably more important, is that you do not specify an `else` path. That might return you a `Unit` instead of a value, so you may want to specify what should be returned otherwise. Finally, the calls within those methods are not chained. Calling `toUpperCase` first doesn't alter anything... It's nearly dead code... So you may want to write something like:

```
val str = with(someStr) {
  toUpperCase().run {
    if (contains("W")) replace("W", "w")
    else this
  }
}
```

However I just used run/let/with to demonstrate its usage, as you already used apply... your shown Java way is of course way easier in this regard and the simplest possible solution is rather the one TheOperator showed by just omitting your condition in the first place as the `replace` is case-sensitive by default.

Comment: This does not return `XYwZ` from input `xywz`

Comment: hehe... yeah... that was a misread on my side... still I can't recommend such a construct ;-)

Comment: +1 Had a similar issue with a different conditional transformation function. Swapping out `apply` for `run` actually made the function return the result of the conditional transformation

Answer (score 1):

Docs of "apply" :

> Calls the specified function block with this value as its receiver and
> returns this value.

So it returns the original value ("this value").

What you should use is "let" instead:

```
val str = someStr.let {
    it.toUpperCase().replace("W", "w")
}
```

But then you could just use:

```
val str = someStr.toUpperCase().replace("W", "w")
```