# Kotlin's Apply not working as expected with Reactor Mono

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I have situation that I fail to understand about Kotlin's *[apply](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html)* method used on a [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io) [Mono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) object. When from within the apply method, I call methods of the mono object, the called Mono methods don't respond at all.

**Example without *apply* (working as expected):**

```
reactor.core.publisher.Mono
    .just(1)
    .doOnSuccessOrError { i, t ->
        println("doOnSuccessOrError")
    }
    .subscribe {
        println("subscribe: value=$it")
    }
```

Which produces the console output:

```
doOnSuccessOrError
subscribe: value=1
```

As expected, first *doOnSuccessOrError()* is called, then *subscribe()*.

**Example with *apply* (works not as expected):**

```
reactor.core.publisher.Mono
    .just(1)
    .apply {
        println("Apply")
        doOnSuccessOrError { i, t ->
            println("doOnSuccessOrError")
        }
    }
    .subscribe {
        println("subscribe: value=$it")
    }
```

Which produces the console output:

```
Apply
subscribe: value=1
```

Now it isn't printing "doOnSuccessOrError" anymore, which is the opposite from what I would expect. Why isn't it printed?

Comment: Use `run` instead of `apply`

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't specific to Mono, but I failed to reproduce it using a simpel test class to generalize the problem. But after reading [Kotlin apply on String not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770167/kotlin-apply-on-string-not-working-as-expected), I understood that it (ofcourse) is caused by immutability of Mono, which also applies to Strings.

So in this code:

```
monoObject.apply {
    println("Apply")
    doOnSuccessOrError { i, t ->
        println("doOnSuccessOrError")
    }
}
```

*apply* is returning the same object as the variable *monoObject* is referring to.
But because of the immutability of Mono, a call to *doOnSuccessOrError()* is returning a new Mono object, which differs from the one *monoObject* is referring to. Since the result of *doOnSuccessOrError()* (a new Mono object) isn't stored at all, the lambda that was given to it won't be called. Which explains the question.

A solution is to use Kotlin's [*run*](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) instead by simply replacing "apply" with "run".